# Polymer 1.x: Resizing chart after page load

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, polymer, polymer-1.0

TLDR; [Here is the jsBin](http://jsbin.com/zumireradi/1/edit?html,output).

How do I initially paint my `<google-chart>` geochart element within the boundaries of my layout and prevent it from "spilling over" on first paint?

In my custom element, I use a `google-chart` element which in turn uses a Google GeoChart and API. When it first appears on screen, it looks like this. (Notice how the right side spills outside the edge of the `paper-card`?)

#### Draws outside boundaries at first

What I actually see on first paint. (Highlighted states were declaratively preset.)

[image: First appearance]

After I select a state (like, say, California in this case) the chart redraws itself and winds up properly drawn within the boundaries like I want it.

#### Redraws inside boundaries after clicking a state

What I expect to see on first paint. And after selecting a state.

[image: Appearance after click and redraw]

## Recreate the Problem

Follow these steps:

1. [Open this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/zumireradi/1/edit?html,output).
2. Click the button labeled <kbd>Reveal Chart</kbd>
3. ❌ Notice the chart now first appears ***larger than*** the max-width of the `paper-card` (100px).
4. Click on a state.
5. Notice the chart resizes to fit inside the width of the `paper-card`.

#### The problem is with the "hidden" attribute of the "div" tag

The problem (when implementing the below solution suggested by @ScottMiles) is here:

```
<div id="chart" hidden> <!-- "hidden" attribute is the problem -->
  <x-element color="red"
             selected='["Colorado", "South Dakota"]'>
  </x-element>
</div>
```

If you remove the `hidden` attribute, the first paint occurs as desired. However, I need the `hidden` attribute on page load for UX reasons.

I have unsuccessfully tried two solutions so far.

#### Solution attempt 1: Manually redraw on Attached

```
attached: function() {
  this.$.geochart.drawChart(); // Called manually to handle page resizes
}
```

#### Solution attempt 2: IronResizableBehavior

```
behaviors: [
  Polymer.IronResizableBehavior,
],
listeners: {
  'iron-resize': '_onIronResize',
},
_onIronResize: function() {
  this.$.geochart.drawChart(); // Called manually to handle page resizes
},
attached: function() {
  this.async(this.notifyResize, 1);
},
```

#### Source

http://jsbin.com/zumireradi/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="google-chart/google-chart.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-card/paper-card.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="x-element">
    <template>
      <style>
        google-chart {
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
      <br><br><br><br>
      <button on-tap="_show">Show Values</button>
      <button on-tap="clearAll">Clear All</button>
      <button on-tap="selectAll">Select All</button>
      <div>[[selectedString]]</div>
      <google-chart id="geochart"
                    type="geo"
                    options="[[options]]"
                    data="[[data]]"
                    on-google-chart-select="_onGoogleChartSelect">
      </google-chart>
    </template>
    <script>
      (function() {
        // Monkey patch for google-chart
        var gcp = Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement('google-chart'));
        gcp.drawChart = function() {
          if (this._canDraw) {
            if (!this.options) {
              this.options = {};
            }
            if (!this._chartObject) {
              var chartClass = this._chartTypes[this.type];
              if (chartClass) {
                this._chartObject = new chartClass(this.$.chartdiv);
                google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(this._chartObject,
                    'ready', function() {
                        this.fire('google-chart-render');
                    }.bind(this));
                google.visualization.events.addListener(this._chartObject,
                    'select', function() {
                        this.selection = this._chartObject.getSelection();
                        this.fire('google-chart-select', { selection: this.selection });
                    }.bind(this));
                if (this._chartObject.setSelection){
                  this._chartObject.setSelection(this.selection);
                }
              }
            }
            if (this._chartObject) {
              this._chartObject.draw(this._dataTable, this.options);
            } else {
              this.$.chartdiv.innerHTML = 'Undefined chart type';
            }
          }
        };
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-element',
          /** /
           * Fired when user selects chart item.
           *
           * @event us-map-select
           * @param {object} detail Alpabetized array of selected state names.
          /**/
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming', ].sort();
              },
            },
            color: {
              type: String,
              value: 'blue',
            },
            options: {
              type: Object,
              computed: '_computeOptions(color)',
            },
            selected: {
              type: Array,
            },
            data: {
              type: Array,
              computed: '_computeData(items, selected.length)'
            },
            selectedString: {
              type: String,
              computed: '_computeSelectedString(selected.length)',
            },
          },
          attached: function() {
            if (this.selected === undefined) {
              this.async(function() {
                this.selected = [];
              }, 0);
            }
          },
          _computeOptions: function() {
            return {
              region: 'US',
              displayMode: 'regions',
              resolution: 'provinces',
              legend: 'none',
              defaultColor: 'white',
              colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#E0E0E0', this.color],
                minValue: 0,  
                maxValue: 1,
              }
            }
          },    
          // On select event, compute 'selected'
          _onGoogleChartSelect: function(e) {
            var string = e.path[0].textContent.split('Select')[0].trim(), // e.g. 'Ohio'
                selected = this.selected, // Array of selected items
                index = selected.indexOf(string);
            // If 'string' is not in 'selected' array, add it; else delete it
            if (index === -1) {
              this.push('selected', string);
            } else {
              this.splice('selected', index, 1);
            }
          },
          _computeSelectedString: function(selectedInfo) {
            var selected = this.selected.sort();
            this.fire('us-map-select', selected);
            return selected.join(', ');
          },
          // After 'items' populates or 'selected' changes, compute 'data'
          _computeData: function(items, selectedInfo) {
            var data = [],
                selected = this.selected,
                i = items.length;
            while (i--) {
              data.unshift([items[i], selected.indexOf(items[i]) > -1 ? 1 : 0]);
            }
            data.unshift(['State', 'Select']);
            return data;
          },
          clearAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', []);
          },
          selectAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', this.items.slice());
          },
          _show: function() {
            //console.log('items', this.items);
            console.log('selected', this.selected);
            //console.log('data', this.data);
          },
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <paper-card style="max-width:100px;">
    <button onclick="unhide()">Reveal Chart</button>
    <div id="chart" hidden>
      <x-element color="red"
                 selected='["Colorado", "South Dakota"]'>
      </x-element>
    </div>
  </paper-card>
  <script>
    function unhide() {
      document.getElementById('chart').hidden = false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The google docs are saying that in your case the resize will be handled by the css, try DOMElement.style.width/height in js with your logic.

Comment: @DanielMizerski: Could you please provide a link to the docs you are describing?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

and also if it resize only by cropping you can add behavior to magnyfying glass, check config options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer generates as much of your application as possible before first-paint to avoid flashing and FOUC. Some elements like `google-chart` are unhappy if they are rendered before a paint has occurred already (because some measurements are not yet available).

Something to try is deferring your initial drawing of the `google-chart`, like this:

1. Leave `selected` uninitialized. This will prevent `chartData` from computing and prevent the chart from drawing prematurely.

   ```
   selected: {
     type: Array
    }
   ```
2. Initialize `selected` asynchronously from `attached`:

   ```
   attached: function() {
     if (this.selected === undefined) {
       this.async(function() {
         this.selected = []; 
       }, 0);
     }
   }
   ```

This a bit of a hack, but calling `this.async(.., 0)` should get you beyond the first-paint. At that point we give `selected` a value, which triggers `chartData` computation and chart drawing.

HTH

Update following OP's published JSbin: forcing the chart to redraw after unhiding it fixes the problem: http://jsbin.com/pekahix/edit?html

```
document.querySelector('#chart').hidden = false;
document.querySelector('x-element').$.geochart.drawChart();
```

Comment: Good idea. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Isn't this the type of situation `Polymer.IronResizableBehavior` was designed to help address?

Comment: If it doesn't work then there is missing information in your example. Can you make a JSBin or equivalent live example (snippet)? It removes the guesswork. `IronResizableBehavior` is designed to address things that need dynamic resizing, it's not clear you need that big of a hammer.

Comment: Here's the demo... http://jsbin.com/zumireradi/1/edit?html,output. When you wrote *If it doesn't work then there is missing information in your example.* You were **spot on** my genius friend. Spot on! That really helped a lot because then I went troubleshooting and discovered the problem is caused by a `hidden` attribute I need for UX purposes. I edited the question to reflect this new information. *(It's always a challenge when writing SO questions to strike the right balance between providing not enough information to discover the problem and too much information that overwhelms others.)*

Comment: See my update above. Fwiw, regarding the challenge of framing questions: it's clear that you put a effort into writing well-formed questions and that makes it a lot easier to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with Polymer.IronResizableBehavior, but the issue was drawChart() I believe, try redraw(). I was able to use your efforts + the [demo of the component](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-resizable-behavior/blob/master/demo/src/x-app.html) to get this resizing simply. I have the width of the chart set to 100% and it scales smoothly to the card it is placed in(which had auto margins to fit to the page)

```
<google-chart
    id="marketchart"
    type="column"
    options='{"title": "Responsive chart",
              "vAxis": {"minValue" : 0, "maxValue": 10}}'
    cols='[{"label": "Data", "type": "string"},{"label": "Value", "type": "number"}]'
    rows='[ ["Col1", 5.0],["Col2", 5.0],["Col3", 5.0] ]'>
  </google-chart>

  <script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-dashboard',

  behaviors: [
    Polymer.IronResizableBehavior
  ],

  listeners: {
    'iron-resize': '_onIronResize'
  },

  attached: function() {
    this.async(this.notifyResize, 1);
  },

  get parent() {
    if (this.parentNode.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE) {
      return this.parentNode.host;
    }
    return this.parentNode;
  },

  _onIronResize: function() {
    this.$.marketchart.redraw();
  }

});
```